# SSIS/SSDT: underlying connection was closed?

Tags: windows, ssis, certificate

I am trying to use Web Service Task in SSIS/SSDT to use our company's Web Service. However I am getting this error: "The error is: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel..". I have installed the certificate to Trusted Root Certificates Authorities but I am still getting that error. I speculate that the issue stems from a mismatch name. Where the domain name does not match the name on the certificate I installed. Is there a solution for this or can I have SSIS/SSDT to ignore this certificate error?